# Knockout not behaving correctly in Pyramid

Tags: javascript, python, knockout.js, pyramid

I'm building a webapp using Pyramid, but Knockout is behaving differently. I have a form:

```
        <div data-bind="with: $root.itemToAdd" style="display: none;">
        <form data-bind="submit: $root.addItem">
            <fieldset style="border: none;">
                <legend >Submit Item</legend>                   
                <label>
                    URL <span>{</span>          
                </label>                
                    <input type="text" placeholder="URL" data-bind="value: url, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>
                    Kwip <span>{</span>         
                </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your description please!" data-bind="value: description, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <button type="button" class="submitAnItem">Add Item</button> 
                <a href="#" class="exit">Cancel</a>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

here is the view model:

```
var ViewModel = function() {

    this.itemToAdd = {
        url: ko.observable(""),
        description: ko.observable("")
    };

    //Behavior
    this.addItem = function () {
        alert('Event fired');
    };
};
```

I can't figure out why when the form is submitted that the 'addItem' function is not fired. I recreated this in another framework and was able to fire the event. Is there something happening in Pyramid that might interfere with my javascript? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Obviously template engine is intersect with Knockouts statements if you use default mako's templates don't forget about dollar sign symbol which is reserved as bultin mako operator ${}

Comment: has it been a long day? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because a type button button will not fire the submit event. you need a button type submit to fire that